# how do you convert a json entries in a file into a data frame?

Tags: json, r

I am trying to read files that has json content and convert that to tabular data based on some fields.

The file includes content like this:

```
{"senderDateTimeStamp":"2016/04/08 10:03:18","senderHost":null,"senderCode":"web_app","senderUsecase":"appinternalstats_prod","destinationTopic":"web_app_appinternalstats_realtimedata_topic","correlatedRecord":false,"needCorrelationCacheCleanup":false,"needCorrelation":false,"correlationAttributes":null,"correlationRecordCount":0,"correlateTimeWindowInMills":0,"lastCorrelationRecord":false,"realtimeESStorage":true,"receiverDateTimeStamp":1460124283554,"payloadData":{"timestamp":"2016-04-08T10:03:18.244","status":"get","source":"MSG1","ITEM":"TEST1","basis":"","pricingdate":"","content":"","msgname":"","idlreqno":"","host":"web01","Webservermember":"Web"},"payloadDataText":"","key":"web_app:appinternalstats_prod","destinationTopicName":"web_app_appinternalstats_realtimedata_topic","esindex":"web_app","estype":"appinternalstats_prod","useCase":"appinternalstats_prod","Code":"web_app"}
```

I need to be able to convert timestamp, source, host, status fields withing payloadData section for each line into a data frame in R.

I've tried this:

library(rjson)
d<-fromJSON(file="file.txt")

```
dput(d)
structure(list(senderDateTimeStamp = "2016/04/08 10:03:18", senderHost = NULL, 
                  senderAppcode = "web", senderUsecase = "appinternalstats_prod", 
                  destinationTopic = "web_appinternalstats_realtimedata_topic", 
                  correlatedRecord = FALSE, needCorrelationCacheCleanup = FALSE, 
                  needCorrelation = FALSE, correlationAttributes = NULL, correlationRecordCount = 0, 
                  correlateTimeWindowInMills = 0, lastCorrelationRecord = FALSE, 
                  realtimeESStorage = TRUE, receiverDateTimeStamp = 1460124283554, 
                  payloadData = structure(list(timestamp = "2016-04-08T10:03:18.244", 
                                               status = "get", source = "MSG1", 
                                               region = "", evetid = "", osareqid = "", basis = "", 
                                               pricingdate = "", content = "", msgname = "", recipient = "", 
                                               objid = "", idlreqno = "", host = "web01", webservermember = "webSingleton"), 
                                          .Names = c("timestamp", 
                                           "status", "source", "region", "evetid", 
                                          "osareqid", "basis", "pricingdate", "content", "msgname", 
                                          "recipient", "objid", "idlreqno", "host", "webservermember"
                                               )), payloadDataText = "", key = "web:appinternalstats_prod", 
                  destinationTopicName = "web_appinternalstats_realtimedata_topic", 
                  hdfsPath = "web/appinternalstats_prod", esindex = "web", 
                  estype = "appinternalstats_prod", useCase = "appinternalstats_prod", 
                  appCode = "web"), .Names = c("senderDateTimeStamp", "senderHost", 
                                               "senderAppcode", "senderUsecase", "destinationTopic", "correlatedRecord", 
                                               "needCorrelationCacheCleanup", "needCorrelation", "correlationAttributes", 
                                               "correlationRecordCount", "correlateTimeWindowInMills", "lastCorrelationRecord", 
                                               "realtimeESStorage", "receiverDateTimeStamp", "payloadData", 
                                               "payloadDataText", "key", "destinationTopicName", "hdfsPath", 
                                               "esindex", "estype", "useCase", "appCode"))
```

Any ideas how I could convert payloadData section of the json entry into a data frame?

Comment: Running your code gives an error: Error in structure(list(timestamp = "2016-04-08T10:03:18.244", status = "get",  : 
  'names' attribute [16] must be the same length as the vector [15]

Comment: @user1357015, I've updated the post with working dput output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be something you want:

```
library(rjson)
d<-fromJSON(file="file.txt")
myDf <- do.call("rbind", lapply(d, function(x) { 
               data.frame(TimeStamp = x$payloadData$timestamp, 
                          Source = x$payloadData$source, 
                          Host = $payloadData$host, 
                          Status = x$payloadData$status)}))
```

Comment: I get this error: Error: unexpected '}' in:
"             Source = d$payloadData$source, 
             Status = d$payloadData$status}"
>     )
Error: unexpected ')' in "    )"
>   )
Error: unexpected ')' in "  )"

Comment: Error in d$payloadData : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: Do you intend to convert only a single list of d or you have multiple d in your file? If it is the former case then `myDf <- data.frame(TimeStamp = d$payloadData$timestamp, Source = d$payloadData$source, Host = d$payloadData$host, Status = d$payloadData$status)` should be good enough for you. I am assuming you have a list of ds to convert.

Comment: @Psidon, the json content is in a file, Each line in the file is json formatted text. I have to read each line and make one big data frame out of it. Your code is not working for me.

Comment: How does the structure of your `d` look like? Is it a list of the structure that you give in your code? If it is, then the modified code should work for you.

Comment: @Psidon, there is this file called test.txt which has many json entries. When I do this: data<-fromJSON(file="nds.txt"), it only reads the first line of the file. I need to be able to read all entries in the log and parse the payloadData section into a data frame.

Comment: Then you may want to try this: `data <- lapply(readLines("test.txt"), fromJSON)`

Answer (score 1):

Consider the package [`tidyjson`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyjson/vignettes/introduction-to-tidyjson.html):

```
library(tidyjson)
library(magrittr)

json <- '{"senderDateTimeStamp":"2016/04/08 10:03:18","senderHost":null,"senderCode":"web_app","senderUsecase":"appinternalstats_prod","destinationTopic":"web_app_appinternalstats_realtimedata_topic","correlatedRecord":false,"needCorrelationCacheCleanup":false,"needCorrelation":false,"correlationAttributes":null,"correlationRecordCount":0,"correlateTimeWindowInMills":0,"lastCorrelationRecord":false,"realtimeESStorage":true,"receiverDateTimeStamp":1460124283554,"payloadData":{"timestamp":"2016-04-08T10:03:18.244","status":"get","source":"MSG1","ITEM":"TEST1","basis":"","pricingdate":"","content":"","msgname":"","idlreqno":"","host":"web01","Webservermember":"Web"},"payloadDataText":"","key":"web_app:appinternalstats_prod","destinationTopicName":"web_app_appinternalstats_realtimedata_topic","esindex":"web_app","estype":"appinternalstats_prod","useCase":"appinternalstats_prod","Code":"web_app"}'

json %>%
  gather_keys()

# head() of above
#   document.id                 key
# 1           1 senderDateTimeStamp
# 2           1          senderHost
# 3           1          senderCode
# 4           1       senderUsecase
# 5           1    destinationTopic
# 6           1    correlatedRecord

json %>%
  enter_object("payloadData") %>%
  gather_keys() %>%
  append_values_string()

# head() of above
#   document.id         key                  string
# 1           1   timestamp 2016-04-08T10:03:18.244
# 2           1      status                     get
# 3           1      source                    MSG1
# 4           1        ITEM                   TEST1
# 5           1       basis                        
# 6           1 pricingdate
```

Comment: @JasonAiskalns, the json data is in a file. I've done this first to read it into an object: data<-fromJSON(file="file.txt"), when I run your code, receiving this error: Error in UseMethod("as.tbl_json") : 
  no applicable method for 'as.tbl_json' applied to an object of class "list"